# Probability the balls drawn from $U_1$ and $U_2$ were white

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory

Let $U_1$,$U_2$ and $U_3$ be urns, and let $U_1$ contain $2$ white and $3$ black balls, $U_2$ contain $4$ white and $6$ black balls and $U_3$ $9$ white and $3$ black balls. A ball is drawn from $U_1$ and put into $U_2$, then a ball is drawn from $U_2$ and put into $U_3$. Finally a ball is drawn from $U_3$ and turns out to be white. What is the probability that the balls drawn from $U_1$ and $U_2$ were white?

Now, I thought i should use Bayes Formula to solve this.

Let $B_1=\{\text{Ball drawn from $U_1$ white}\}=2/5$

Let $B_2=\{\text{Ball drawn from $U_1$ black}\}$

Let $B_3=\{\text{Ball drawn from $U_2$ white}\}$

Let $B_4=\{\text{Ball drawn from $U_2$ black}\}$

Let $A$ is event that ball drawn from $U_3$ is white.

$P(B_1\mid A)=\frac{P(B_1)P(A\mid B_1)}{P(B_1)P(A\mid B_1)+P(B_2)P(A\mid B_2)+P(B_3)P(A\mid B_3)+P(B_4)P(A\mid B_4)}$

However, here i think i'm making a mistake. Which way should i follow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Bayes I arrived at this:

$$\eqalign{
  & P({W_1}{W_2}|{W_3}) = {{P\left( {{W_3}|{W_1}{W_2}} \right)P\left( {{W_1}{W_2}} \right)} \over {P\left( {{W_3}} \right)}}  \cr 
  & P({W_1}{W_2}|{W_3}) = {{{{100} \over {715}}} \over {{{100} \over {715}}{\rm{x}}{9 \over {13}}{2 \over 5}{6 \over {11}}{\rm{x}}{{10} \over {13}}{3 \over 5}{4 \over {11}}{\rm{x}}{9 \over {13}}{3 \over 5}{7 \over {11}}}} = {{100} \over {517}} \cr} $$

Answer (score 2):

As you said the probability that the first ball is white is $\frac{2}{5}$. Conditioned on the fact that the first ball was white the second ball will be white with probability $\frac{5}{11}$ and conditioned on this being the case the last ball will be white with probability $\frac{10}{13}$.

This gives you a total chance that all 3 balls are white of WWW: $\frac{100}{715}$

We now contrast this with the chances of the last ball being white while not both of the others are white. There are three cases and I give the probabilities below:

WBW: $\frac{2}{5}\frac{6}{11}\frac{9}{13}= \frac{108}{715}$

BWW: $\frac{3}{5}\frac{4}{11}\frac{10}{13}= \frac{120}{715}$

BBW: $\frac{3}{5}\frac{7}{11}\frac{9}{13}= \frac{189}{715}$

In the end you are looking for:

$$\frac{WWW}{WWW+WBW+BWW+BBW}= \frac{50}{50+108+120+189}=\frac{100}{517}$$

Comment: I think you computed the probability for a WWW case wrong

Comment: You are right I missed a factor 2.